# Accessing Math functions from rootpy

Tags: python, root-framework, pyroot

I'm currently trying to access Math functions such as DeltaR from rootpy, but I'm not sure how this is done.  I've seen nothing in the documentation or in any examples.  The C++ equivalent would be something like:

`double dR = ROOT::Math::VectorUtil::DeltaR((jets)[i],(partons)[i]);`

But I'm unable to find a rootpy or even pyroot equivalent that'll work.  If I try in pyroot with

```
import ROOT as r
r.Math.VectorUtil.DeltaR(jets[i],partons[i])
```

I get the error:

`AttributeError: type object 'ROOT::Math' has no attribute 'VectorUtil'`

When it quite clearly should, unless I don't understand correctly what it means by 'Attribute'.  Anyway, I don't want to ask pyroot questions here :) I just put this down to a quirk in the way that pyroot handles such things, which is why I thought I'd give rootpy a try.  I'm not sure if this is possible however.

Cheers,
Joseph

Comment: You are being a little fuzzy about the difference between http://www.rootpy.org/ and http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/pyroot. Which one are you using?

Comment: I removed the rootpy tag since this has nothing to do with rootpy specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions from `ROOT::Math::VectorUtil` are in `libGenVector` which is loaded automatically in neither CINT nor PyROOT. Manually loading it (like you probably do in your `root_logon.C`) makes the functions available, e.g.

```
import ROOT as r
r.gSystem.Load('libGenVector')

# ...

r.Math.VectorUtil.DeltaR(jets[i],partons[i])
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm guessing it's usable in rootpy via the pyroot wrapper, which means this might be a worthy addition to the documentation.

Comment: When you `import ROOT as r` you are using the PyROOT bindings, not rootpy (it is also in `rootpy.R`). The example you gave doesn't depend on rootpy at all.

Answer (score 0):

If jets and partons are TLorentzVectors then you should be able to do:

```
from ROOT import *
dR = jet.DeltaR(parton)
```